# How do I enable folders on my computer to allow php to move files into them?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

So, I am trying to upload files using PHP into a folder, however, the images are not appearing. There are no error messages. I would think an error would appear to tell me they were unable to be uploaded.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['postsubmit'])) {

    $postTitle = trim($_POST['posttitle']);
    $postAuth = trim($_POST['postauthor']);
    $postStat = trim($_POST['poststatus']);
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $postTags = trim($_POST['posttags']);
    $postDate = date('y-m-d');
    $postContent = trim($_POST['postcontent']);
    $postComCount = 4;

    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image");

}

?>

<h1>Add New Post</h1>

<div class="col-xs-6">
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="posttitle">Post Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="posttitle" id="posttitle" class="form-control" maxlength="99"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postauthor">Post Author</label>
        <input type="text" name="postauthor" id="postauthor" class="form-control" maxlength="25"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postauthor">Post Status</label>
        <input type="text" name="poststatus" id="poststatus" class="form-control" maxlength="25"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postauthor">Post Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postauthor">Post Tags</label>
        <input type="text" name="posttags" id="posttags" class="form-control" maxlength="25"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postcontent">Post Content</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="postcontent" id="postcontent" class="form-control" rows="15" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="postsubmit">Submit Post</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing `move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image");` to `move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/".$post_image);`

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image");
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/".$post_image);
```

It is because you are just passing a string `$post_image` rather than the variable itself

Answer (score 0):

Add error reporting to debug, something like this:

```
if (! move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image") ) {
    echo 'move failed: ';
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
```